# Regex to match an optional '+' symbol followed by any word

Tags: java, regex

In Java I want to use a  regular expression to match a string that may or may not start with plus symbol and then contain any word after that.
 like +adm, adm  both should match .

I tried `[\\+?\\w\./]+`   but it is not working .

Comment: did you give it a try yet? Also _I want a regular expression_ is not what you ask here @ SO!

Comment: Well, presumably you've already tried *something*. Please show that, along with how it's not working for you.

Comment: *"Please help need urgent."*  It is not wise to mention your time constraints.  It makes it sound like you feel your question is more deserving of attention than any other question.

Comment: yes i gave a try , for eg. i want +adm to be matched by this regular expression [\\+?\\w\\./]+ , but this expression is not capturing +adm , but capturing all other string .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to give a literal `+` followed by the `?` quantifier (it means "zero or one of these") followed by whatever *character class* you want to use for "word". You may also want a capture group. All of these things are explained in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

---

Re your edit:

> I tried `[\\+?\\w\./]+` but it is not working .

You don't want the whole thing in `[]`, as that denotes a character class. To create a capture group, use `()`, not `[]`. So you *may* want `new Pattern("(\\+?\\w+)")`: An optional literal `+` followed by one or more word characters, all within a capture group. Or do it without a capture group: `new Pattern("\\+?\\w+")`. *(I show the `new Pattern` bit so it's clear that this is within a string literal, hence escaping the backslashes. Java **really** needs a literal regex notation.)*

Comment: Thanks Mr.Crowder.. it was really helpful ..

Comment: @learner: Re your edit: I've updated the answer.